# Spring way of sharing global state?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, global-variables

When maintaining global state in an application there are two main concerns -

1. Sharing global constants
2. Sharing global dynamic state

For `(1)` I use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to inject global constants into beans.

For sharing global dynamic state I create a central class with public static members. e.g.

```
public class GlobalState {
    public static MyObject myObj;
}
```

I cannot inject `myObj` as its state needs to be computed at run time and then shared among all the modules of the application.

I'm not comfortable with the tight coupling in the above approach. Statics make it hard to refactor the code. Later on if I want to apply an `Aspect` on all read calls to `GlobalState` that is not possible.

What is the best way to manage global dynamic state using Spring?

Here are two **hypothetical**(don't know if Spring facilitates these) solutions in my head -

1. Placing `myObj` into the spring context dynamically at runtime. And
   then asking Spring to re-inject the new instance into all the beans
   that declare a dependency (null can be injected initially when
   context was initialized).
2. Have a Struts like `ValueStack` in Spring, on which I can place my
   primitive values and other classes can load it from there using
   context reference.

Comment: When you say _state needs to be computed at run time_, does it mean once in the life-cycle of application or multiple times ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you inject `GlobalState` and make your calculated data available by instance methods?

Also, I don't understand why you cannot inject the results of your runtime calculation (`myObj`)? You can e.g. implement `InitializingBean` to trigger a calculation after all relevant parts of the application have started (just inject what you need for you calculation, Spring takes care of the instantiation order).

#### UPDATE

Other possibilities are to [define beans being the result of a static factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method), or to create a [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) that does your computation and adds the computation result to the application context.

Comment: First point is good. However, Implementing InitializingBean means the beans themselves become responsible for doing computation. I want to inject result of computation done by a separate component. To put it more succinctly - is it possible to inject a dependency into a bean some time other than at context load time.